# PHP migration 5 to 7, advice on what to check

Tags: php, migration

I have a big system that needs to migrated from php5 to php7. I have found tool PHP Code Fixer that helped me finding all the deprecated function and I fixed them all. But there is another thing that causes problem. I have found in the code a lot of people were returning function call in a function, something like this.

```
function test($array) {
    return reset(callSomeArray($array));
}
```

This will fail as reset function expects a variable as a parameter. In php5 this worked but not in php7. This is correct way:

```
function test($array) {
   $callArray = callSomeArray($array);
   return $callArray;
}
```

Since this is a big software, and I cannot read the all code and test everything. I found out that reset function is causing the problem, but how to find other function that are used the same. Is there some document, or checklist, what to check for migration. Like, list of functions that expect a variable?

Comment: What about [this?](https://www.php.net/migration70)

Comment: I have gone through this document, but I could not find the talk about the functions that cannot accept function as a parameter. Or I missed it :)